# Динамическая страница

Tags: jquery, php, html, javascript, css

У меня есть область, которая заполняется новостями к примеру

```
 <div id="content"><?php 
/*То что заполняет страницу новостями динамически из бд*/ ?>
</div>
```

Вопрос в следующем, подскажите, пожалуйста, где найти, почитать, изучить, куда двигаться, да бы сделать следующее:
Если много новостей в бд, они начинают растягивать страницу в низ до бесконечности, нужно сделать, что бы определённое количество новостей выводилось на странице, ну и можно было бы листать и выбирать количество выводимых новостей.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Пагинация - в принципи](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)
Пагинация - на php, например: [тут](http://www.pagination.ru/) или [тут](http://it-giki.ru/post/414.html)
[CSS:Overflow](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

Comment: То, что нужно спасибо большое!

Comment: Примите ответ (галочка слева), если помогло - проголосуйте (пальчик вверх).

Comment: Эм понил))

Comment: Еще можно сделать в стиле веб2.0 с автоматической подгрузкой, аля фейсбук и т.п.